# Pushout and pullback in the category of rings

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider the following pushout diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>f>> B\\
@V g V V @VV  V\\
C @>> > D
\end{CD}
in the category of $\textbf{Rings}$ where $f,g$ both are flat monomorphisms. The diagram is also a pullback diagram.

I'm trying to show that it's a pullback diagram but could not.

Comment: I believe that the statement is true. I did not find any argument to prove it. If it is not true, please give a counter-example.

Comment: What are you trying to prove? That it's also a pullback diagram?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to prove that it's a pullback diagram @HarryWilson

Comment: The statement is wrong: Take $A = \mathbb Z, B = C = \mathbb Q$. Then $D = \mathbb Q$, and the maps from $B$ and $C$ are isomorphisms, so that the pullback is $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: I claim that the multiplication map $\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ and the "left inclusion" $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q\otimes_{\mathbb Z}\mathbb Q$ are inverse bijections. The composition $\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ is obviously the identity, so that the other composition is surjective since $\frac{m_1}{n_1}\otimes \frac{m_2}{n_2} = n_2\frac{m_1m_2}{n_1n_2}\otimes \frac{1}{n_2} = \frac{m_1m_2}{n_1n_2}\otimes 1$. But a retraction where the inclusion map is surjective is already an isomorphism.

Comment: Do you mean all associative rings or only commutative ones?

Answer (score 8):

As I've written in the comments, the pushout square
$$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb Z @>>> \mathbb Q\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathbb Q @>>> \mathbb Q
\end{CD}
$$
is not a pullback square, providing a counterexample. However, there are additional hypotheses which work, namely that one of the maps is faithfully flat.

Suppose first that one of the maps (say $f$) has a section $r:B\to A$, i.e. $rf =\operatorname{id}_A$. Then we have a splitting of $A$-modules $B = A \oplus\ker r$, and the pushout square becomes
$$
\begin{CD}
A @>i_1>> A\oplus \ker r\\
@VgVV @Vg\oplus hVV\\
C @>i_1>> C\oplus (\ker r\otimes_A C)
\end{CD}
$$
which obviously is a pullback square.

Since the $A$-module $B$ is flat, the functor $-\otimes_A B$ preserves finite limits. In particular, writing $A' = B\times_D C$ which receives a map $A\to A'$, the induced map $A'\otimes_A B\to (B\otimes_A B)\times_{D\otimes_A B} (C\otimes_A B)$ is an isomorphism. The composition of this map with the left inclusion $B\to A'\otimes_A B$ is then exactly the map from the top left corner to the pullback in the diagram obtained by taking the pushout over $A$ with $B$ everywhere; in particular, the top horizontal map $B\to B\otimes_A B$ has a section, namely the multiplication. By the result of the previous paragraph, the map from $B$ into the pullback, and hence also into $A'\otimes_A B$, is an isomorphism. Thus the map $A\to A'$ becomes an isomorphism after tensoring with $B$; if $B$ is faithfully flat, it must have been an isomorphism in the first place.

This argument is inspired by (and probably an application of) the theory of faithfully flat descent, compare [the Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03O6).